# test send mail, wrong test email account

Tags: email

I want to test the outgoing mail settings, but CiviCRM sends the test mail to one of the contacts in the database (last name Adams).
Why does it associate this person with my account? How can I change that?

ps:  I do have a contact in CiviCRM with the same email as my WordPress account.  I also tried creating a test contact that was called AAAtest.

Temporary Solution:  This isn't really a solution, but I created a new WordPress account using my personal email address.  I had a test contact in CiviCRM that used this email address, and they are now associated with each other.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Civi are you using?  There is a place to put in the email address to send the test email to.  Depending on the version it may default it but you can change it to something else.  Is it populating with Adams or is does it have your email address but then sends it to something different?

Comment: version 4.6.4 -  When I tested it the first time, it didn't have a space to enter the email, it just had a pop up/confirmation that said "message sent to...(wrong address)"

Comment: Also, when I create a new mailing it says that the mailing was created by Adams (not me)

Comment: is it possible that your WP account has been synched with the wrong civi record. in drupal you will see the user id next to the civi id in the top right part of your Summary screen for your/their record

Comment: Thanks, I see that this user has "CiviCRM ID / User ID" in his profile, whereas mine only has "CiviCRM ID" for the same field.  I can't change the value though.

Comment: Crystal, what you will want to do is to alter the civicrm_uf_match table to correct which contact record should be linked to the civicrm record. Once you have done that it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seamus' comment has the correct answer.

CiviCRM links each WordPress login with a corresponding contact.  Your WordPress login is tied to the wrong contact - maybe a messed-up import, an incorrect merge, it's hard to say!

This is going to lead to multiple problems, including the one you're seeing, and you need to fix this ASAP.  If you or someone you know is comfortable with SQL, then changing `civicrm_uf_match` to match your WordPress ID with the correct CiviCRM contact is the best solution.

If not, you can use the API Explorer to change it - but make sure you have a backup of your database before trying, the API Explorer is powerful enough to wreck things!

- Go to **Support menu > Developer > API Explorer**.  "Support" menu might be called "Help" menu, it switched somewhere in 4.6.
- Set "Entity" to "UFMatch", "Action" to "Get".  In "Parameters", Set "CiviCRM Contact ID" to Adams.
- Press "Execute".
- In the "Results" area below the "Execute" button, note the value of "id".  There are two "id" values - you want the one INSIDE the "values" stanza.
- Keep "Entity" as "UFMatch", change "Action" to "Delete".  For "UFMatch ID", put in the ID you just found.  Press execute.

At this point, Adams should no longer be tied to your account!  Assuming your WordPress email address and CiviCRM email address match, CiviCRM should link the two on your next login.

Comment: Will this affect Adams' membership data or contact info?

Comment: Thank you.  This worked, and my Wordpress account is now associated with my account in CiviCRM.